# How to structure sagas depending on an API accessToken

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux-saga

I have a saga `loginSaga` that performs the api call to get an `accessToken`.
Once this succeeds I'd like to have bunch of other sagas to spin up that download data with this `accessToken`

Those sagas depend on the `accessToken`, so they should only run until `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` appears. Then they should finish. If they were currently in the process of downloading something this should be canceled, the result ignored.

This is what I have now:

```
function *authorize(credentials) {
  try {
    const { email, password, device_name, device_family, device_token } = credentials
    const { access_token, user } = yield call(api.loginAsync, email, password, { device_name, device_family, device_token })
    yield put(actions.loginSuccess(access_token, user))
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
    if (!isCancelError(error)) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status == 401) {
        error.message = "E-Mail or Password wrong"
      }
      yield put(actions.loginError(error))
    }
  }
}

function *loginFlow() {
  while(true) {
    console.info("Waiting for account/LOGIN")
    const credentials = yield take(actions.LOGIN)
    const authorizeTask = yield fork(authorize, credentials)

    console.info("Waiting for account/LOGOUT")
    const { type } = yield take([actions.LOGOUT, actions.LOGIN_ERROR])
    cancel(authorizeTask)
    if (type == actions.LOGOUT) {
      yield call(api.logoutAsync)
      yield put(actions.logoutSuccess())
    }
  }
}
```

Then the on `LOGIN_SUCESS` depending sagas:

```
function *refreshUser() {
  while (true) {
    const result = yield take([actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, actions.REFRESH_USER])
    try {
      const user = yield call(api.getUserAsync)
      yield put(actions.userRefreshed(user))
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }
}


function *getActivities(access_token) {
  console.info("fetch activities")
  try {
    const activities = yield call(api.getActivitiesAsync, access_token)
    console.info("activities fetched")
    yield put(activitiesUpdated(activities))
  } catch (error) {
  }
}

function *updateActivities() {
  while (true) {
    const { access_token } = yield take(actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
    console.info("Calling getActivities")
    yield call(getActivities, access_token)
    while (true) {
      const {type } = yield take([actions.REFRESH_ACTIVITIES, actions.LOGOUT])
      if (type == actions.LOGOUT) {
        break
      }
      yield call(getActivities, access_token)
    }
  }
}
```

And since they all need the `accessToken` they all have to wait until the `LOGIN_FINISHED` because this carries it in the payload.

Also my sagas are all started at the beginning and wait.

I thought maybe, when the `authorize` flow finishs it could then spin up the `loginDependingSagas` with the `accessToken` as a param.

like so:

function forkLoginDependingSagas(accessToken) {
  fork refreshUser(accessToken)
  fork updateActivities(accessToken)
}

Is that a good pattern?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Lee See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a separate saga that waits for actions that carry the `access_token` and then fork sagas depending on this `access_token`.

```
function* authorizedFlow() {
  let payload
  while (({ payload } = yield take([actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, actions.START_SIGNUP_SUCCESS]))) {
    const { access_token } = payload
    yield fork(logoutFlow, access_token)
    yield race({
      watchers: [
        call(refreshUser, access_token),
        call(refreshInvoices, access_token),
        call(refreshPendingTransactions, access_token),
      ],
      logout: take(actions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS),
    })
  }
}

function* logoutFlow(access_token) {
  while (yield take(actions.LOGOUT)) {
    try {
      yield call(api.logoutAsync, access_token)
      yield put(actions.logoutSuccess())
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(actions.logoutError(error))
    }
  }
}
```

The logoutFlow would ensure that the `race` between the `access_token` dependent sagas would lead to cancellation of them in case the logout is succcessful.